# How to call Json in sql query

Tags: json, sql-server

I want to  display the parameter ST and NextTime from table @json. The parameters id and Timestamp appear normally. I try the following but does not show any effect.Any possible answers?

My Json

```
{
    "PCol": [{
        "Id": 15,
        "TimeStamp": "2018-02-1",
        "Val": {
            "States": [{
                "Numbers": {
                    "Number": [5, 8]
                },
                "CS": {
                    "ST": "25"
                },
                "Changes": [{
                    "NextTime": 1
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

My Sql Query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json),N'$.PCol')
WITH (   
    [Id]  INT  N'$.Id   ',
    [TimeStamp]  NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.TimeStamp',
    **[ST]  INT N'$.Val.States.CS.ST'**

)
```

Thanks

Comment: That JSON isn't valid; is that your full JSON? (If you try to parse it, you get the error `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 0.`)

Comment: Without valid JSON, we can't help you. `OPENJSON` doesn't work on  invalid JSON.

Comment: Sorry I fix it , now is valid

Answer (score 1):

Not going to lie, my `OPENJSON` knowledge is poor (so this might be able to be more succinct), however, this works:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = 
N' {
    "PCol": [{
        "Id": 15,
        "TimeStamp": "2018-02-1",
        "Val": {
            "States": [{
                "Numbers": {
                    "Number": [5, 8]
                },
                "CS": {
                    "ST": "25"
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
} ';

SELECT P.Id,
       P.TimeStamp,
       V.ST
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,N'$.PCol') WITH ([Id]  INT  N'$.Id ',
                                     [TimeStamp]  NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.TimeStamp',
                                     [Vals] nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Val' AS JSON) P
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Vals,N'$.States') WITH (ST int N'$.CS.ST') V
```

For the latest JSON, this works:

```
SELECT P.Id,
       P.TimeStamp,
       V.ST,
       C.NextTime
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,N'$.PCol') WITH ([Id]  INT  N'$.Id ',
                                     [TimeStamp]  NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.TimeStamp',
                                     [Vals] nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Val' AS JSON) P
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Vals,N'$.States') WITH (ST int N'$.CS.ST',
                                                    [Changes] nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Changes' AS JSON) V
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.[Changes]) WITH (NextTime int '$.NextTime') C
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if i want to display plus the parameter NextTime i will do the same thing ? (i.e I'll put two Cross APPLY )

Comment: Updated the answer for your @chrysa22 .

Comment: i want your help again to display the parameter Number.I try this                                                                                                                            
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Value,N'$.States') WITH (Number  NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.Numbers.Number') K  , but this displays the column  Number  with NULL elements

Comment: "Parameter number" @chrysa22? You'll likely be better off asking a new question, comments are difficult to decipher code from.